# Vite + React wasm errors when running rollup browser-side

Tags: reactjs, vite, webassembly, rollup

I'm trying to run the following rollup example: [How do I run rollup in the browser?](https://rollupjs.org/faqs/#how-do-i-run-rollup-itself-in-a-browser)

My stack is a fresh Vite + React project, to which I only added the @rollup/browser package. When running the code in the example I get the following error:

[image]

I tried running the project on a clean jsfiddle with only the @rollup/browser package and it works just fine, so the problem is within the Vite configuration.

Anyone can help in solving this issues?

I also tried adding the vite-wasm plugin https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/package/vite-plugin-wasm and also added the [following plugin](https://github.com/mycelial/mycelial-js/issues/25#issuecomment-1533305723).

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excluding `@rollup/browser` from optimizeDeps worked for me.

In `vite.config.js`:

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite'
export default defineConfig({
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ["@rollup/browser"],
  },
});
```

Many thanks to [Anik Das](https://github.com/sadn1ck) who suggested this fix over in https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/14609 and https://github.com/curran/rollup-v4-browser-vite-demo/pull/2#issuecomment-1766852103

Here's a fully working repository with this fix incorporated:

https://github.com/curran/rollup-v4-browser-vite-demo/tree/main